# Writing large files in c++

Tags: c++, io

I am writing large files, in range from 70 - 700gb. Does anyone have experience if Memory mapped files would be more efficient than regular writing in chunks?
The code will be in c++ and run on linux 2.6

Comment: What kind of system are you running on, that you have 700gb of _RAM_?

Comment: Linux 6.x?  Did I miss Linux 4 and 5?

Comment: @X-Zero Where did you get the requirement of 700GB of RAM?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Sorry, it was a typo. i meant linux 2.6.x

Comment: Unrelated: I highly recommend not having a single file that big.  Make it lots of smaller files.  Please.

Comment: @vcsjones, Jimm - While I'm aware that you may be able to get addresses for more 'memory' than your system posses in RAM, it's pretty much pointless if you don't have (at least a significant portion of) that in RAM, as the only other way I know of to _retain_ that data would be to **page it out to disk**.  I think I've heard of systems that _do_ have a terabyte of RAM (or equivalent) - mostly in the enterprise level, as Big Iron.

Comment: @X-Zero i never specified any lookup or search options. so why do i need a significant portion of 700gb in ram?

Comment: If you're just doing straight writes, then @Hans's answer applies.  Unless you're the one actually writing them, I would doubt you'd be able to do significantly better than the utilities provided with the OS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing the file from the beginning and onwards, there is nothing to be gained from memory mapping the file.

If you are writing the file in any other pattern, please update the question :)

Comment: With memory mapped, you can avoid buffer copying from user space to kernel

Comment: The buffer copying shouldn't be the bottleneck. RAM speed is still a magnitude or two above the sequential write speed of harddisks. But [this beast](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4879/ocz-zdrive-r4-cm88-16tb-pcie-ssd-review/3) gets somewhat closer with 2,5 GB/s sustained sequential write speed.

Comment: @Jimm: Ok. So you have an hypothesis with a good basis. The only way to know if memory mapped will help you in your specific case is to test in your specific configuration. Also consider Hans Passant's analysis; Is there possibly anything to be gained from improving the software in your case? We can not know.

Answer (score 2):

Typical sustained hard drive transfer speeds for consumer grade drives are around 60 megabytes per second, with the sun shining, a stiff breeze in the back and the file system not too fragmented so the disk drive head doesn't have to seek too often.

So a hard lower limit on the amount of time it takes to write 700 gigabytes is 700 * 1024 / 60 = 11947 seconds or 3 hours and 20 minutes.  No amount of buffering is going to fix that, it will quickly be overwhelmed by the drastic mismatch between the disk write speed and the ability of the processor to fill the fire hose.  Start looking for a problem in your code or the disk drive state only when it takes a couple of times longer than that.

Comment: Are you referring to a single drive or a particular raid configuration ?

Comment: 60 MB/s is _very_ conservative. For streaming data, this can easily brought up to the 300 MB/s range, my cheapo raid0 here manages to do 260 MB/s with `dd`. Enterprise SSD are getting close to 1 GB/s these days.

Comment: These are comments that are unprovably correct, the OP didn't document what he's got.  Key point here is that this is a *hardware* issue.  He can apply the calculation to his specific machine capabilities as well as anybody.  And set the lower limit to know what to expect.